# Can Apollo convert messages based on consumer protocol?

Tags: stomp, mqtt, apollo

Does ActiveMQ Apollo automatically convert messages between connected clients protocols ?

What I'm trying to do is have one producer use one protocol (STOMP or any other) but let the consumers choose their protocol as they wish, so they could be MQTT, STOMP, AMQP, OpenWire, etc.

Can Apollo convert messages depending on what protocol the consumer implemented ?  If not, is there a different way than to have to implement all protocols as producers on different topics and tell clients which is their queue, based on protocol, something like

topic/stomp/chat
topic/mqtt/chat

Thanks!

Comment: You can vote for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/APLO-267 -  Support rich protocol conversions of messages.

Comment: Does it work with the accepted answer - using mirrored queues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just convert messages depending on the consumer but, in theory with Apollo you can try Mirrored Queues feature to duplicate the queues/topics for a set of protocols.
http://activemq.apache.org/apollo/documentation/user-manual.html#Mirrored_Queues